# Facebook API post on newsfeed

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook API for posting in group and pages. I dont see an endpoint where I can post on my own newsfeed. What I see is only I can share content via fb link. Does someone know where could I find the endpoint on posting on own newsfeed? Thanks.

Comment: There is no way. You have to use the Share dialog

Comment: so the only way is the share dialog? but for pages/groups, you can custom post. right @WizKid?

Comment: Yes for users you have to use the share dialog